# Find out largest subset of an Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, undirected-graph

Input: a list of vertexes and an adjacency list.

Output: largest subset of good vertexes.

(We say a vertex in a subset as "good vertex" if it has at least 2 adjacent vertexes and at least 2 non-adjacent vertexes in that subset.)

Example 1:

```
Vertexes: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Relations: [(1,2), (1,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)]
```

[image: example]

```
output: []
```

Example 2:
[image: example2]

```
output: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Because for each vertex in the output, it has at least 2 vertexes connected, and at least 2 vertexes not connected with it.

Comment: Is [2,4,5] ok too? What does 2 adjacent vertexes and 2 non-adjacent vertexes mean?

Comment: @YanhuiZhou sorry not a good example, in the example it will return an empty subset. I will put another one later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a vertex "okay" if it has at least two neighbors and at least two non-neighbors in the graph. A vertex must be okay to be in the output.

Remove all non-okay vertices from the graph. As you do this, previously okay vertices may stop being okay as they run out of neighbors or non-neighbors; these vertices also can't be in the output, so treat them like any other non-okay vertices and remove them too. Keep going until all remaining vertices are okay.

Output the set of remaining vertices.

Comment: How do you check a vertice is non-okay? Checking a vertice has at least two non-neighbors is not very effective, the complexity is very high.

Comment: @YanhuiZhou: The number of non-neighbors is the number of nodes left minus the degree of the node, minus 1 because we don't count the node itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the vertices which has less than two neighbors.
2. Build a complement edges(relations) of the left vertices. The complement has no same relation in the origin relation set, but has others. Combine the origin relation set with the complement, it becomes a relation set which is the full relations with the left vertices.
3. Remove the vertices which has less than two neighbors in the complement. The result vertices is the output.

The remove process in step1 and step3, is recursive process. It must remove the vertices until no one can be removed.